# Print Booklet feature in indesign is Shuffling my pages?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, booklet

Indesign has a very handy feature only id doesn't seem to be working for me. I have set up a 20 page document with facing pages (1 being the cover and 20 the back) the second page is designed to be blank, and an introduction on the third page. when I selected print booklet for a mockup it shuffled all the pages forward, so the introduction is now immediately after the cover and my back page is now set as page 18 (18- designed to be a blank page) and I have a blank page as my back page (20) and as page 19(19 was meant to be index, but printed on 17 instead). can someone help me with this? i tried to explain myself as best I could hope it isn't confusing I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Not sure if this can help, but when exporting a PDF with some software, you have an option to "ignore blank pages"; maybe you have this option when printing from InDesign. Make sure it's not checked.

Comment: Ive tried this and you were right my print blank pages option was  off and i ticked it and it has now worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go-meek added a comment to my question and he said to make sure when I'm in the print dialogue box, to tick the "print blank pages" option (inDesign CC) I have tried this and has worked. Thanks so make sure you set up the printer to print the actual blank pages or it will ignore your ones and add it's own.

Answer (score 0):

When printing or exporting a booklet you need to make sure you set the booklet type correctly, this determines how Indesign shuffles the pages so that the end result will be correct when binding the booklet.

Comment: How do I set it up correctly please? and does that mean setting up my pages as (20,1 - 2,19 - 18,3) etc?

Comment: How are you planning on binding the booklet ? With a staple in the middle ? You should not need to re-order your pages youself, that is the function of the print booklet part. Have you tried printing the result ? it's easier to understand what indesign is doing when you have the printed booklet (or a few pages) in your hands.

Comment: Yes basic two staples in the middle. I have printed it yes after pressing print booklet and the pages moved which is my problem.

Comment: Have you printed it on physical paper, so you can hold it in your hands and lay the papers on top of each other and folded it to see the result ?

Comment: yes. I have it in my hand printed. and folded and layered and stapled and it printed wrong.